# defaults not defined while using pickadate with laravel mix $.extend($.fn.pickadate.defaults, {... .

Tags: laravel-mix

I tried to mix jquery and pickadate but it says defalts not defined although it is already defined exactly.

**app.js**

```
let $, jQuery;
jQuery = window.$ = window.jQuery = $ = require('jquery/dist/jquery.min');
require([
 'pickadate/lib/picker',
 'pickadate/lib/picker.date',
 'pickadate/lib/picker.time'
]);
require('my.js');
```

**webpack.mix.js**

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix'); 

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js/');

...
```

**This is how it define by default of picker.date.js**

```
DatePicker.defaults = (function (prefix) {

    return {

        // The title label to use for the month nav buttons
        labelMonthNext: 'Next month',
        labelMonthPrev: 'Previous month',

        // The title label to use for the dropdown selectors
        labelMonthSelect: 'Select a month',
        labelYearSelect: 'Select a year',

        // Months and weekdays
        monthsFull: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
        monthsShort: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
        weekdaysFull: ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'],
        weekdaysShort: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
        ...
        }
    }
})(Picker.klasses().picker + '__')
Picker.extend('pickadate', DatePicker)
```

here is the defaults that undefined

```
$.extend($.fn.pickadate.defaults, {
  selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
  ...
});
```

jQuery is loaded and no prob with method $(...).

Maybe there is someone know about this ^^.

I don't know why this happen, I hope I will get a good solution here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, its my bad, I should use 'jquery' instead of 'jquery/dist/jquery.min' to work with plugin.